# Xero-Api PKCE authorization returns 'Invalid_grant'

Tags: xero-api, pkce

I'm following the instruction here at https://github.com/XeroAPI/Xero-Postman-Tutorial-PKCE-Edition to integrate with Xero. On step 7 'Receive and Set your Access and Refresh Tokens', I get 'Invalid_grant' message. Authorization with Xero works well with return code & uri. I generated a new code, still the same error. Any help? Thanks

Comment: Hi Michael, can you please update your question to include your clientId, and I'll take a look at some logs to see where you've gone wrong

Comment: Hi, I changed all the parameteres and tried again, it works now. Thanks